# How do I know if I am executing something on the UI thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety

I wrote a test to experiment with RestKit using blocks. I thought that the `RKRequest.onDidLoadResponse` would need to contain a `dispatch_async()` call to get the response on the main UI thread, though to my surprise this turned out to cause a runtime exception, so I took it out and I could update the interface quite fine.

My code in question is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)loadSeasons:(UIButton *)sender {
    [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/api/v1/seasons" usingBlock:^(RKRequest* req) {
        req.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse* res) {
            NSLog(@"Request Performed: %@", res.bodyAsString);
            self.textResponse.text = res.bodyAsString;
            //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //    NSLog(@"In main queue: %@", res.bodyAsString);
            //});
        };
    }];
}
```

If I uncomment the `dispatch_async` block I get the exception. So how do I know when I need to use this and when I should not need to? Should I test for something that tells me if the code being executed is on the main thread or not?

I am new to Objective-C and it's early days for me so I do apologise for what may be a newbie question.

**UPDATE**: When uncommenting the code above the following happens:

1. The console outputs the text `(lldb)` in blue, no other information is provided.
2. A break on `libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:`is shown in the editor on`0x1c2009b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi`with the message in green:`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40000008)`.

Comment: It might be helpful to list what kind of exception are you getting? Your console should say.

Comment: I've now added the information I can see, as I'm still learning I'm not sure how to provide more. I should apologise but it's the access to `res.bodyAsString` that causes the problem if called within `dispatch_async`.

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC. Though if there are differences in how to determine if your on the right thread with ARC or not I would like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question you can check your current thread by calling `[NSThread isMainThread]`. However, you DONT need to do this for your issue and in fact its perfectly legal to dispatch an execution block to the main thread if you are already running in the main thread.

The crash is because of the way that variables are stored when executing a block. When the first block is completed the stack memory used by the variable can be overwritten, so by the time your async `NSLog` statement runs in the second block, your variable `res` has been destroyed, so its pointing to garbage when its used in your log statement, triggering a crash.

For completeness, research `__block` variable declarations. To make `res` referenceable in your second dispatch block I believe you'd have to declare it as a `__block` variable to move it to heap by declaring this in your first block: `__block RKResponse* response = res;` and then using `response` in your dispatched log statement.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense. In my case though, could you explain why it works without needing to do `dispatch_async`, I was very surprised to find that the `onDidLoadResponse` block was actually on the main thread. Is this just something that RestKit is conveniently doing for me? Thankyou for your answer foggzilla.

Comment: RKClient is executing your execution block on the main thread because that's probably the thread you made the original call on. 
It is good practice for implementing async apis yourself to check your current execution queue and run any blocks passed to you on the same queue, so it is consistent for programmer, and that's probably what RKClient is doing.

Comment: Thankyou foggzilla, that is exciting and welcomed. Coming from Java and C# you normally have to marshal the thread back yourself to get it onto the interface thread, though in .NET the `BackgroundWorker` does do this for you. Sorry to go off topic, was just explaining where my confusion came from. Thanks again for your help foggzilla!